# Apply a class to every nth template element with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, templating

I've been experimenting with [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/), reworking an existing project.

My current layout has the logic to determine if the rendered `<div>` tag is the first or fourth item.

```
if (index % 4 == 0) addClass('omega');
if (index % 4 == 1) addClass('alpha');
```

Is there any built-in functionality of knockout that can template similar conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options for you:

- there is work being done to add a `$index` variable when doing a `foreach` in KO. This is scheduled to be included in KO 2.1.  The pull request is here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/182
- there is a `repeat` binding here: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat that gives you better access to the actual index.
- if you are using an observableArray, then there is an easy way to create an index each item.

It would look like this:

```
//track an index on items in an observableArray
ko.observableArray.fn.indexed = function() {
   //whenever the array changes, make one loop to update the index on each
   this.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       if (newValue) {
           var item;
           for (var i = 0, j = newValue.length; i < j; i++) {
               item = newValue[i];
               if (!ko.isObservable(item.$index)) {
                  item.$index = ko.observable();
               }
               item.$index(i);      
           }
       }   
   }); 

   this.valueHasMutated(); 
   return this;
};
```

You would initialize an observableArray to be indexed like:

```
this.myArray = ko.observableArray().indexed();
```

Now, when the observable array is manipulated, it will take one pass through the items and correct the index.  This is better than inside your `foreach` looking up the index of each item each time.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen these indexing options before. I think my problem is that I expect the templating to change CSS based on observableArray item removal.

Comment: The index will be re-built anytime that the array is manipulated (through observableArray methods), so when you remove an item it will keep the index updated.