# Knockout.js print index of object in foreach

Tags: knockout.js

This is probably quite simple but I can't seem to find it readily. In knockout.js, How would you print the index of an item in an observable array that you are iterating over using the foreach binding?

Comment: In KO 2.1.0 (beta is available now), you can use `$index` to get the index within a foreach.  Here is the beta thread: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/LdUfjGNZOj8/discussion.  Similar to what Matt describes in his answer below, I use this technique (add `indexed` function to observableArrays): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760861/apply-a-class-to-every-nth-template-element-with-knockoutjs

Comment: @RPNiemeyer: I'm about 98% sure I stole it from you on the Knockout forum!

Comment: @MattBurland no worries!

Comment: @RP Thanks, since I'm just poking around for the time being I'll check that out, great stuff.

Comment: 2.1.0 is now out of Beta. In fact, `$index` is used as Example 2 on their ForEach Binding docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: The accepted answer was good at that time, but Ashish's answer below should be the accepted answer currently IMHO. Cheers

Comment: @Mtz Agreed, I will change it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

knockout 2.1 has added good new option $index.
Here is example http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Answer (score 11):

You can't. Not directly anyway. I use this function myself to add an index property to objects in my ObservableArrays:

```
    function indexSubscribe(array) {
        array.subscribe(function() {
            for (var i = 0, j = array().length; i < j; i++) {
                var item = array()[i];
                if (!item.index) {
                    item.index = ko.observable(i);  
                } else {
                    item.index(i);  
                }
            }
        }); 
   };
```

Then in my ViewModel, I can do something like this:

```
this.whatevers = ko.observableArray();
indexSubscribe(this.whatevers);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution might be late answer. But If your preferable choice is with `viewmodel` the below solution will helps with latest fix.

According to `Knockout 3.1.0` and above libraries has simple work around. The `index` can be passed as secondary argument to the `arrayForEach`.

```
var items = ["Mercedes", "Volvo", "BMW"];

ko.utils.arrayForEach(items, function(item, index) {
    console.log(item + ' ' + index);
});
```

Hope this solution might helps someone.